# Synchronized scrolling is not perfect between 2 wx HyperTreeLists

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Intro summary: I need to create a side by side difference viewer between 2 tree objects in which i can fully customise text colour and background colour for each item.

Python version:  3.5.4

wxPython version:  4.0.3

Structure: wx.Dialog containing 2 derived HyperTreeLists using a horizontal boxsizer.

Code (stripped version with only the required parts; the trees will always have the same size as expand and collapse are in sync):

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.hypertreelist as HTL

class AutoColumnSizeHTL(HTL.HyperTreeList):
    def __init__(self, parent, agw_style, column_name):
        super().__init__(parent, agwStyle=agw_style)
        self.parent = parent
        self.AddColumn(column_name)
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, 350)
        self.main_window = self.GetMainWindow()
        self.root = self.AddRoot("")
        self.current_item = None
        self.twin_tree = None

        self.main_window.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.on_scroll_change)

    def add_new_item(self, text, fg_color):
        self.current_item = self.main_window.AppendItem(self.root, text)
        self.main_window.SetItemTextColour(self.current_item, fg_color)

    def add_new_item_child(self, text, fg_color, bg_color):
        child_item = self.main_window.AppendItem(self.current_item, text)
        self.main_window.SetItemTextColour(child_item, fg_color)
        self.main_window.SetItemBackgroundColour(child_item, bg_color)

    def set_twin_tree(self, twin):
        self.twin_tree = twin

    def OnSize(self, event):
        row_width = self.parent.GetSize()[0] / 2
        scrollbar_width = 21
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, row_width-scrollbar_width)
        super().OnSize(event)

    def on_scroll_change(self, event):
        scroll_units = self.main_window.GetScrollPos(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.twin_tree.main_window.Scroll(-1, scroll_units)
        event.Skip()
```

[Initial Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlS5D.png)

[After 1 nudge of WheelDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipLXr.png)

PS: I'm using 2 hypertreelists with 1 column each instead of 1 hypertreelist with 2 columns because i could not figure out how to change the colour of the item in the 2nd column. If you happen to know how to do this that would also solve this nuisance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.main_window.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.on_scroll_change)

def on_scroll_change(self, event):
    delta = event.GetWheelDelta()
    rotation = event.GetWheelRotation()
    lines_per_action = event.GetLinesPerAction()
    lines = rotation / delta
    if lines != 0:
        lines = lines * lines_per_action
        vsx, vsy = self.twin_tree.main_window.GetViewStart()
        scroll_to = vsy - lines
        self.twin_tree.main_window.Scroll(-1, scroll_to)
        self.main_window.Scroll(-1, scroll_to)
```

event.Skip() did the opposite of what i was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using an up-to-date Phoenix installation, then HyperTreeList has a SetItemBackgroundColour(item, colour, col) method to set the background colour per column.

Comment: Unfortunately updating wxpython is not an option.

Comment: You don’t need to update wxPython... simply grab a copy of HyperTreeList and put it in your local folder...